# How to get the data from api on button click in nextjs on server side

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am new to next.js and seeking some help from you amazing people.

I want to know how to get the data from API on button click in next.js on server side.

I have idea that we cant use onclick without making it client but I don't want to make it client.

Here is my code where I am getting data directly from server:

```js
import Button from "@/components/button/Button";
import { get } from "@/services/ApiService";
import React from "react";

const getData = async() => {

    console.log("data from server")
    const response = await get(`posts`)
    return response?.data
}


async function About() {

  const data = await getData();
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      Welcome to About test
      <Button data="posts" />
      {data &&
        data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>{item.id}</div>
              <div>{item.title}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Comment: Perhaps if you redirect to a new route on the button click, you will get a new render and `getServerSideProps` will be called again.

Comment: it will help me alot if you can you please give a little more insights of your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is similar to this?

You need to a button handler to trigger the function on click so then you can set an internal component state to then render the data.

```
import Button from "@/components/button/Button";
import { get } from "@/services/ApiService";
import React, {useState} from "react";

const getData = async() => {
    console.log("data from server")
    const response = await get(`posts`)
    return response?.data
}


const About = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const handleClick = async() => {
        const endpointData = await getData()
        setData(endpointData)
    }

  return ( 
    <div>
      Welcome to About test
      <Button onClick={handleClick} />
      {data &&
        data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>{item.id}</div>
              <div>{item.title}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

But the approach mentioned in the comments is something like this where you can get the data before the page loads from the server and then just render it in without button click. But you could optionally choose to store it in another state value and then load that already retrieved data on click, sort of acting like a isVisible state.

```
import Button from "@/components/button/Button";
import { get } from "@/services/ApiService";
import React from "react";

const getData = async () => {
  console.log("data from server");
  const response = await get(`posts`);
  return response?.data;
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = await getData();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

const About = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Welcome to About test
      <Button />
      {data &&
        data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>{item.id}</div>
              <div>{item.title}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```